# .hta want Windows Script Host Exec() to function more like Run()

Tags: javascript, windows, hta

I have an html application that is performing several tasks through javascript.  Some do not require that I know when they finish, so I use ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").Run().  Some tasks I do not want to wait for because I have other things to do, but I need to know when the are finished so I can begin a dependent task, so I use ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").Exec() and can monitor the WshScriptExec object returned in a javascript setInterval().

The tasks in question are batch files that call visual studio builds, some distribution batches, etc.  The main batch displays its own output, and the items it calls have windows and other output that they display.

The problem I have is that Exec() creates a child command shell, and the batch it calls does not show, and the windows of the processes it calls do not show.  I do not want to capture stdin/out/err, but would like to make Exec() act more like Run() and just kick off the batch, but returning the WshScriptExec so I can monitor if it has completed.

Is this possible in any way, or is there some other kind of workaround?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that you can't get `cmd.Status` from this: `var cmd = WScriptShell.Exec("some_prog");`?

Comment: no, I am able to get the status correctly, and check its value.  The trouble is none of my batches output is displayed, and the windows that it opens do not display.  The processes can be seen in task manager.  I am guessing this is because Exec() creates a child command shell?  thank you

Comment: Doesn't `Status` turn to `1` when the `Exec` is finished? Also I can see a CMD window when launching a batch file using `Exec()`. Maybe writing `wscript /i s` to CMD prompt helps to see the windows?

Comment: yes Status does turn to 1 when finished, and that is functioning correctly.  I noticed that my batch was hanging until I added myobject.StdOut.ReadAll() and StdErr.ReadAll().  I now get the windows of the programs my batch calls, but not the output of the batch itself.  I will look into the wcript suggestions

Comment: More information.  I DO see the cmd window open when running Exec() but it does not display any output.  If I keep checking stdOut in my javascript I get the output my batch would be displaying.  I have tried creating a batch that would then CALL the real batch to see if that would open up another cmd window which would display the output, but it does not.

Comment: When you write `cscript` to command prompt, it shows a list and short explanation of the arguments, maybe setting something else would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var e=sh.Exec("%comspec% /c testbatch.bat >con")
```

It is not perfect: the batch file will have no access to input and the output may be distorted if there are some control sequences in it. But it does allow you to see what is going on.